# Javascript, pausing audio in function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, audio, pause

I have created a game that acts as a showcase for my portfolio.

However I want the audio to pause when a certain function is called

```
var aud = document.getElementById("#music");
```

I created a variable that acts as the stand in for the music

```
function web(i){ 
    aud.pause(); //I try to pause the variable here
    keysPressed = {};
    if (!jumping){$("#guy").css({"background-image":"url(img/Character-Stand.gif)"});}                                          
    window.open(pickup[i].weblink);
};
```

I don't know what I have done wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where does the audio element get played?

Comment: Describe how it does not work.

Comment: Please show us what `#music` is, how `web` is called, and describe what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't say exactly where you initalize your `var aud = document.getElementById("#music");` and also not how you define your audio-tag. But below I have a minimal working example how to pause an audio.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function pause() {
    var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    aud.pause();
}
</script>

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
    <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<button onclick="pause()">pause</button>
</body>
</html>
```